# calling urlrewrite from code

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, seo

I have a url as a string and I want to call the asp.net code (IIS7 module) that rewrites urls on their way into my application and get a rewritten url from it:

`http://webserver/nice/url/youHaveThere`

to

`http://webserver/app/Default.aspx?category=nice&catalog=url&pageid=youHaveThere`

I want to call this function from inside an asp.net application. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have the module already installed on your server, and are just asking about defining a specific rule. [This](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/) is where you can read everything you need about creating rules.

The rules are all done through regular expressions, not my forte. But this is a format example:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to article.aspx">
      <match url="^article/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="article.aspx?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The ([0-9]+) stands for number only patterns, ([_0-9a-z-]+) stands for text and number. I would think this would work for what you're tying to:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to Default.aspx">
      <match url="^article/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="app/Default.aspx?category={R:1}&catalog={R:2}&pageid={R:3}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: I have rules already. I want to pass a url through those rules and get a resulting rewritten url

Comment: I see I assumed wrong, you know what they say about assumptions. If you're trying to have IIS do something for you from a web form, this would be the place to start: http://goo.gl/DODm6  You can't call the module independently in the code behind, but they have the AJAX UpdatePanel Control. You might be able to use something like that to interface with IIS, depending on a lot of factors obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think you'd call a "rewrite rule".  Instead you'd just use a Regex Replace.  Maybe something like:

```
string nice_url = "http://webserver/nice/url/youHaveThere"
string new_url = Regex.Replace(nice_url, @"/(?<category>\w+)/(?<catalog>\w+)/(?<pageid>\w+)$", "app/Default.aspx?category=${category}&catalog=${catalog}&pageid=${pageid}");
```

Comment: nah, I have a number of rewrite rules in my web.config - I want to run a url string through those rules and get what the rewritten url would be if I visited the site